# Destroy DataTable and recreate using newly fetched data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to reinitialize `jQuery DataTable` with newly fetched data. I have read several posts with similar problem and the solution involves destroying the existing dataTable before re-initializing. The table renders well initially but when trying to render it again with change in the number of columns I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. I understand that this error occurs when the HTML column count and the column definition for DataTables do not match. This implies that the initial table was not successfully destroyed. Here is the code:

```
var dataSet1 = [{
    "country": "Benin",
    "year": 1996, 
    "water": 70.0
  },{
    "country": "Vietnam",
    "year": 1996, 
    "water": 95.1
  }];

  var dataSet2 = [{
    "country": "Benin",
    "year": 2000, 
    "water": 75.8, 
    "electricity": 58.5    //additional column from the database
  },{
    "country": "Vietnam",
    "year": 2000, 
    "water": 96.8, 
    "electricity": 63.2 
  }];

  $('#example_dt').DataTable({
    data: dataSet1,
    columns: [
        { data: "country" },
        { data: "year" },
        { data: "water" }],
    'searching': false
  });

  $('#update_data_btn').click (function(){
  //$("#example_dt").DataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#example_dt').DataTable({
      destroy: true,
      //retrieve: true
      data: dataSet2,         
      columns: [
        { data: "country" },
        { data: "year" },
        { data: "water" }, 
        { data: "electricity" }],
    // "bDestroy": true,
    'searching': false
      } );
  });   
});
```

I have tried various suggestion below from similar posts but  but can't seem to get this resolved. The same error still comes up.

```
[1] Adding destroy: true
[2] Adding $("#example_dt").DataTable().fnDestroy();
[3] Adding retrieve: true  
[4] Adding "bDestroy": true
[5] Using $('#example_dt').empty(); //this empties and new table not created
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amotha/yqutoh3d/16/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with both destroy and empty approach. Check fiddle link below:

```
$('#example_dt').empty();
```

Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pw4cm9ok/)